# How break dynamic creation of goroutines on error?

Tags: go

I want to create as many go-routines as i need to complete a certain task in parallel.
I know I will get an error when there are enough routines created, and the order of execution of these routines does not really matter.

How can i break out from a loop creating these routines?
Here's a half pseudo-code example of what I want to achieve:

```
func main() {
  for {
    //This function will give an error after N runs
    //I just don't know which before running.
    go myFunc()
     if err != nil {
      break
    }
  }
  //Wait for all routines to finish
  //Do something with returned data.
}
```

I realize this might not be the best approach to the problem after searching around for a while. So any suggestions on how to best solve the problem would also be appreciated.

Comment: The problem with this loop is that there's no guarantee than any of the `myFunc` functions will even be scheduled before you run out of resources. Can you call the function first, and then dispatch the work? You could also have N worker goroutines, where you find what value of N is most efficient, and have those each call `MyFunc` until the work is exhausted.

Comment: Another thing to look at is working pools. Basically instead of trying to initiate more goroutines on the fly and having to compensate for scheduling time, you use pre-existing worker routines that are managed by a worker pool. Then you give work to the pool's interface and the pool distributes the work to workers that are already primed for working. something to keep in mind with this approach is having the appropriate input and output buffers to avoid deadlocks

Comment: A worker-pool seems to be the way to go. I was somehow hoping Go would magically solve this for me. Thanks.